# Angular Material with features modules and Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having troubles using Angular material with Angular 6 whenever I want to use features modules.
Here is my project's structure :

```
app/
|- app.component.ts
|- app.component.html
|- app.module.ts
|- app-routing.module.ts
|- homepage/
  |- homepage.module.ts
  |- homepage-routing.module.ts
  |- pages/
    |- homepage.component.html
    |- homepage.component.ts
    |- homepage.component.css
|- inbox/
  |- inbox.module.ts
  |- inbox-routing.module.ts
  |- pages/
    |- inbox.component.html
    |- inbox.component.ts
    |- inbox.component.css
```

Both inbox and homepage are lazy loaded.
I'm trying to use Angular Material in both `homepage.component.html` and `inbox.component.html` (I want to use MatButtonModule) but failing to do so and the official documentation doesn't help me.

Here is what I tried :

- If I try to import MatButtonModule into both `homepage.module.ts` and `inbox.module.ts`, the app will crash with this error 
  `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`.
- If I try to import MatButtonModule into only one module, it will work only for the component binding to this module.
- If I try to import MatButtonModule directly into `app.module.ts` it just won't work at all.

So my question is, how can I use Angular Material with features modules, what is the best practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to make another module and name it MaterialModule and place it in the root of your application , then export all material modules which you want to use in you'r app i.e MatButtonModule like below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

And then import **MaterialModule** into both modules ( inbox.module.ts and homepage.module.ts )

If this solution won't work , add you'r code into [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so I can check exactly what is you'r code's problem.

Good luck

Comment: Dublicate. Also contains imports that are not necessary.

Comment: Not necessary codes removed, and its not duplicate. it's you'r complete you'r answare.

Comment: Hi, i know it's late for this but, is it okay (performance wise) to load the MaterialModule on each Feature Module?

Comment: If you import it in each module, the application does not load it every time, it just loads it once and uses it several times.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `material.module.ts` shared module which exports all Angular Material modules. Afterwards import the material module in both of your modules. The Module can look like.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ],
  exports: [ MatButtonModule ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Comment: exports: [ MatButtonModule ] is enough , no need to import MatButtonModule